# How do you secure Web API 2.0 endpoints?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I have several Web PI endpoints currently secured with an access key. I'm not opposed to abandoning this security model.

Now, we're building a web app that will consume the services. The front end will have a login screen to secure portions of the application. I also want to make the Web API services available for use by applications other than our own (think public API).

How should I secure my services and allow access from our own web UI and as a service?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to secure Web API 2.0 endpoints.

It seems like you already secured your endpoint with an access key, no idea how your clients know the access key.

For your web app I would ask:

1. How is the user logging in as you described? What authority are they providing their credentials to? Can you use that authority to attach a token to the requests of your web service?
2. You mention you also want to provide a public access through a public api. What credentials will they have? What authority will they request access from? You could set this up many ways with different types of credentials e.g. user name and password/client certificate/access key.

Microsoft has some really good resources about this including:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Securing-ASPNET-Web-APIs

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security

Answer (score 0):

I can think of:

- [HTTP Basic Authentication](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication)
- [OAuth/OpenID Connect](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server)
- [Client and Server Certificates](https://www.piotrwalat.net/client-certificate-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-windows-store-apps/)